# jQuery.attr("style") vs jQuery.css()

Tags: jquery, css

My colleague uses this code to show an element:

```
$('selector here').attr('style','display:inline-block');
```

I normally use this:

```
$('selector here').css('display','inline-block');
```

I know inline CSS using the `style` attribute is a bad practice, but other than that, does any of these two lines result in a higher-precedence CSS, or are these two lines completely identicaly from the point of view of how the element will look like?

I was assuming that `.css()` may have a lower precedence because inline CSS has a bigger priority.

Comment: As an aside to your question, neither are ideal. You should use `show()` instead

Comment: Why `show()` is better?

Comment: Because it completely decouples the CSS from the JS code.

Comment: When the element has `display:none` in the css, `show()` will add `display:block` to the `style` attribute of the element as you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vem5qL2c/1/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both add the style attribute to your element. I'd say the only difference is the readability of your code when you set multiple CSS attributes at once. Other than that, `css()` adds style, and only replaces if already exists. By using `attr('style', ...)` you replace the whole style attribute every time.

Let's say you have an element as below:

`<div class='element' style='color:red'>test</div>`

When you use `$('.element').attr('style', 'display:none')` this would result in:

`<div class='element' style='display:none'>test</div>`

When you'd use `$(.element').css('display', 'none')` this would result in:

`<div class='element' style='color:red;display:none'>test</div>`.

Using `css()` also allows you to set multiple style attributes while keeping your code readable:

```
$('.element').css({
    color: 'red',
    textDecoration: 'underline',
    // etc.
})
```